# What are the api to delete the folder and replace in java?

Tags: java, nio, apache-commons

i want to know any apis that can copy and replace folders along with its contents.I know about apache commons, but that copies into the destination folder, it doesnt delete the destination folders extra contents

Comment: https://www.google.de/?gws_rd=ssl#safe=off&q=java+move+folders

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can be done with standard java
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html
this solution is available from 1.7 onwards

Comment: java nio files works for files and not for folders right ?

Comment: i dont want to move it, only copy and  replace

Comment: still the link is valid for your case and Files is working on paths, which can be files or directories. Please read the docs thouroughly